# K-Means not resulting in elbow shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

I'm trying to use k-means in a dataset available at [this link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing#) using only the variables about the client. The problem is that 7 of the 8 variables are categorical, so I've used one hot encoder on them.

To use the elbow method to select an ideal number of clusters I've ran the KMeans for 2 to 22 clusters and plotted the inertia_ values. But the shape wasn't anything like an elbow, it looked more like a straight line.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

bank = pd.read_csv('bank-additional-full.csv', sep=';') #available at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing# 

# 1. selecting only informations about the client
cli_vars = ['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'housing', 'loan']
bank_cli = bank[cli_vars].copy()

#2. applying one hot encoder to categorical variables
X = bank_cli[['job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'housing', 'loan']]
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X_2 = X.apply(le.fit_transform)
X_2.values
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(X_2)

one_hot_labels = enc.transform(X_2).toarray()
one_hot_labels.shape #(41188, 33)

#3. concatenating numeric and categorical variables
X = np.concatenate((bank_cli.values[:,0].reshape((41188,1)),one_hot_labels), axis = 1)
X.shape

X = X.astype(float)
X_fit = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

X_fit

#4. function to calculate k-means for 2 to 22 clusters
def calcular_cotovelo(data):
    wcss = []
    for i in range(2, 23):
        kmeans = KMeans(init = 'k-means++', n_init= 12, n_clusters = i)
        kmeans.fit(data)
        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    return wcss

cotovelo = calcular_cotovelo(X_fit)

#5. plot to see the elbow to select the ideal number of clusters
plt.plot(cotovelo)
plt.show()
```

This is the plot of the inertia to select the clusters. It's not in an elbow shape, and the values are very high.

[image]

Comment: hey, what do you know about your data? how great is it? I will try this dataset, but this may not be a code issue...

Comment: As you are hot-enconding, you are increasing the dimensionality of the data and as shown here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93488/usefulness-of-k-means-clustering-on-high-dimensional-data this may have some issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K-means is not suited for categorical data. You should look to k-prototypes instead which combines k-modes and k-means and is able to cluster mixed numerical and categorical data.

An implementation of [k-prototypes is available in Python](https://pypi.org/project/kmodes/).

If you consider only the numerical variable however, you can see an elbow with k-means criteria:

[image: k-means on numerical data only]

To understand why you do not see any elbow (with k-means on both numerical and categorical data), you can look at the number of points per clusters. You can observe that each time you increase the number of clusters, a new cluster is formed with only a few points which were in a big cluster at the previous step, thus the criterion is only a few less than at the previous step.